# client closed connection in nginx error log

Tags: nginx, openresty

I am using openresty with redis for a project.
I am getting these messages in nginx error.log.

> 2016/07/13 23:08:05 [info] 28306#0: *110027 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 27.97.70.20, server: 0.0.0.0:80

Total number of connects opened and count of this message is almost same. I see that lots of people see this message on different context, and see varying responses on different places.

How should I proceed? Is this issue serious?

Comment: It is normal use case - connection was closed before request was send back. There are a lot of reasons for that, for example 27.97.70.20 IP  belongs to India, Idea Cellular Limited. So it is mobile client, it may lost a connectivity for many reasons. Hint - disable INFO logging for production system.

Comment: Did you find the problem ? I have same issue